# Recursive javascript function to find the shortest distance between 2 points thats greater than 1

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, graph-theory

I have a set of points and an object that describes how each point is linked to one another.

Here is a simplified example:

```
const points = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

const links = {
    a : [ "b", "f" ],
    b : [ "c", "f" ],
    c : [ "d", "e" ],
    d : [ "a", "e" ],
    e : [ "c", "d", "f" ],
    f : [ "a", "b", "e" ],
};
```

In this example 'a','b','c','d' describe the corners of a rectangle and 'e','f' are points inside of the rectangle that link to 2 corners each.

```
b ------------ c
|\            /|
| \          / |
|  f ------ e  |
| /          \ |
|/            \|
a ------------ d
```

I am trying to work out a recursive function that returns all possible outcomes where the distance (steps) between the points is greater than 1 to form polygons.

Desired output:

```
output = [
    [ "a", "f", "b" ],
    [ "b", "f", "e", "c" ],
    [ "c", "e", "d" ],
    [ "d", "e", "f", "a" ],
]
```

There would obviously be duplicate results if the points order were reversed so ideally, in ascending order a->d, heading around the perimeter, forming polygons as you go. ie;

start: a,
end: b,
result: [ a, f, b ]

start: b,
end: c,
result: [ b, f, e, c ]

start: c,
end: d,
result: [ c, e, d ]

start: d,
end: a,
result: [ d, e, f, a ]

More specifically I would like a function that would return the desired result given a start and end point, eg:

```
function shortestPath(data, start, end) {
    // ... magic ...
    return result;


result = shortestPath(links, 'b', 'c')
// [ "b", "f", "e", "c" ]
```

Apologies if any of this is unclear - first time posting on SO.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you're missing some data.  If you're counting hops, then `B -> C -> D` is shorter than `B -> F -> E -> D`.  And if there are actual physical distances involved, then you need your data structures to supply them.

Comment: thanks for your response, just realized I was lacking some important details, was trying to not over complicate it initially. Hope the update has provided better insight to the problem I am looking to solve. Cheers

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Naturally I started by filtering out points, then looping over the results the find potential solutions then sorting to find the minimum steps however, it was pretty clear to me that as the complexity increases this is not a realistic solution... I can see that a recursive approach over looping is clearly the way to go but I honestly don't know how to go about structuring a function of this type in this circumstance - hit a bit of a wall and struggling on where to go with it guess that's where/why i am seeking some direction and guidance. Cheers

Comment: You probably want to investigate [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).  That seems perfectly tailored to solving this.

Comment: Yeah that was the algorithm I was looking at but struggled to wrap my head around it partially because it related to distance rather than incremental steps but should be able to adjust for my need. Will have another crack today, thanks for the suggestion :)